# Getting GCC error when using SQLite and Fast Math: "SQLite will not work correctly with the -ffast-math option of GCC"

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to compile a C project and I'm getting the error "SQLite will not work correctly with the -ffast-math option of GCC". I was wondering how to either bypass this error(though I am unsure of the implications of doing so) or any other solution that might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the SQLite source code, you'll see that this error comes from SQLite's fallback implementation of `sqlite3IsNaN`, which relies on IEEE's quirky definition of the `!=` operator when used with NaN operands.

If you have a working `isnan` function in your C library, you can `#define SQLITE_HAVE_ISNAN`, which will make SQLite use the existing `isnan` instead of rolling its own.

Or, you could just compile SQLite without `-ffast-math`.

Comment: FWIW, here is the code in question: https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/artifact/d9eb0a6c4aae1b00

Comment: I think you missed the root cause: OP has some wacky CFLAGS in their environment.

Comment: This fixed my problem, I was working on a project where I could change the CFLAGS. So this was the correct solution for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because you configured the build with the gcc option `-ffast-math` in your CFLAGS. Probably what's going on is that you have exported default CFLAGS in your environment, perhaps from your `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`/`.profile`. If so, you really should remove that, because `-ffast-math` is harmful and will break code not designed to be used with it.

To fix this, first clean the build tree entirely and start from scratch. Then either remove the CFLAGS from wherever they're getting set, log out, and log back in, or `unset CFLAGS` at the shell before running the build system's configure script or similar.